# how to manipulate KafkaStreams KeyValueStore

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using KafkaStreams to kafka of messages and persist the accumulated state in a KeyValueStore.
But I also need to programmatically affect the state of that KeyValueStore from an API call.
This would be easy if I had a reference to the `Processor` or perhaps even the `KeyValueStore` but I don't have a reference to either.

I am creating a `Topology` which takes a `ProcessorSupplier` and a `StoreBuilder` so that I don't have a reference to the `Processor` and `Store`. It looks like

```
final MyProcessorSupplier processorSupplier = ...;
final StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<PriceKey, Short>> storeBuilder = ...;
final Deserializer<SubscriptionRequest> deserializer = ...;
final Topology topology = new Topology();
topology.addSource("Source", new StringDeserializer(), deserializer, topic)
        .addProcessor("Process", processorSupplier, "Source")
        .addStateStore(storeBuilder, "Process");

streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, kafkaClientSettings.toProperties());
streams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new LoggingStreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler(topic));
streams.start();
```

so the actual `Processor` and `Store` are created inside the KafkaStreams code with no reference visible to me.

So is there a way that I can manipulate the KeyValueStore directly or pass in synthetic messages to the Processor?

I'm using kafka 2.8.2 but plan to update to 3.5 soon, if 3.5 has a better way to do this.

Comment: p.s. I've had this working for years with "org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.Processor" by simply having the supplier return the same instance every time, but it's deprecated and when I tried to switch to "org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.Processor" I found out that it forces you to use a supplier that does not return the same instance each time (it actually creates 2 of them just to check that they are not ==).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to effect the stream state from an external source which is generally not a recommended practice. It is not because such operations remove processing guarantees that Kafka Streams library provides.

The best way of approaching your issue is to use an extra topic. Have your API calls publish the necessary events to that topic, and then use the processor API to properly handle the store from that stream. That way you maintain all the processing guarantees that come with Kafka Streams. It will also allow you to move away from constructing your topology by hand, and rely on the DSL and custom processors.

Your implementation would look like so:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
  private final KafkaTemplate<String, MyObject> template;

  @PostMapping("/my-api")
  public void post(@RequestBody MyObject object) {
    kafkaTemplate.send("my-topic", object.getKey(), object);
  } 
}
```

Meanwhile your implementation of topology, assuming Processor1 handles your current stream, and ProcessorAPI handles events from API, I also skipped serde details for brevity.

```
var stream1 = streamsBuilder.stream("my-old-topic")
   .process(() -> new Processor1("my-store-name"), "my-store-name");
var stream2 = streamsBuilder.stream("my-api-topic")
   .process(() -> new ProcessorAPI("my-store-name"), "my-store-name");
stream1.merge(stream2);
```

Now both processors have access to the store, processing guarantees are maintained and API calls are handled. On top of that you have access to all of DSL syntax.